# Notepad++, how to count tabs in a tab delimited file?

Tags: notepad++

I've got a tab delimited file, is there an easy way for me to count the total number of tabs on a line?

I have opened it up in excel, but excel is limited to 256 columns and I think each line of my file has more than this limit

I've found the option in notepad++ to show tabs as arrows, but that doesn't help me determine how many there are, and I don't really want to have to count each one manually

If there isn't an easy way in notepad++, what are my other options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could search for the tab character in the file. Go to **Search** -> **Find...**, in the **Find what** field paste the tab character (it will probably look like a box) and click on **Count**. Unfortunately, this only gives you the total number of tabs in the document, not the total number of tabs in the line, even if you choose the **In selection**.

Comment: The OP could simply resolve that by temporarily limiting the file to one line.

Comment: He could do that, I know. I was just telling him the whole story so he's aware of the limitation.

Comment: You can also search for the tab character as  `\t` if you have search mode set to "Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)"

Comment: Alternately, you can _replace_ a tab with a tab, which would give you the option of only including those that are in the selection; a count of the replacements made is shown upon completion.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the tabs in that line into a enter character and count how many lines you have. the number of tabs would be equal to the total number of lines - 1.